# Can JPA used with EE 5 servers

Tags: java-ee-5, jpa-2.1

Can JPA 2.1 be used in EE 5 servers? I want to benefit the option of calling stored procedure capability. Iknow JPA can be used in a stand alone but i woder if this will has any affect on transactions management when used as a managed entity manager by the server as the specs specify that only JPA 1 which must be supported

Comment: Which is the Application Server?

Comment: Its IBM websphere 7.0

Comment: WebSphere 7.0 supports JPA 2.0 when you install the feature pack. JPA 2.1 support is not available.

Comment: dkaustubh, I Knew that. But thanks for your answer. At least you responded.

Answer (score 0):

[JSR 338: JavaTM Persistence 2.1](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338) support is available starting from [Java EE 7](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/java_ee_7_key_features)

`Java EE 7` application servers could be found on [official Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html)